# Mongoose children.id function throws TypeError in instance method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi guys i'm a Mongoose/NodeJs newbie, what i'd like to achieve is to have a handy method for setting a property for a subdocument child of a document.

*Example: in a shopping order with predefined coupons i would like to set that one of these is been used by a user with a referenceId.*

I thought a clean solution was to put that logic in an instance method but when i run that the nodemon executable says that `this.children.id` is not a function... maybe i'm in the wrong scope or there is some knowledge i'm missing?

```
ParentSchema.methods.setRefPropertyForChild = function setRefPropertyForChild(
  refId
) {
  const toUpdate = this.children.find(child => !child.property);
  this.children.id(toUpdate._id).set({ ref: refId });

  return toUpdate;
};
```

Thanks

---

Here is what i came up for the solution

```
for (const child of this.children) {
    if (!child.propertyRef) {
      child.propertyRef = refId;
      return child;
    }
  }

return false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that children is an array of subdocuments, it indeed shouldn't have any id property.

Try this to achieve something you need :

```
ParentSchema.methods.setRefPropertyForChild = async function setRefPropertyForChild(
  refId
) {
  const affected = []

  for (const child of this.children) {
    if (!child.property) {
      child.ref = refId
      affected.push(child)
    }
  }

  await this.save()

  return affected;
};
```

It will search and modify subdocuments and then call instance's save method, which should take care of updates.

Note that i've used async/await syntax there (and that's something that you too probably want to use).

Comment: Thanks! You made my day! Although i didn't seem to quite understand why the subDoc doesn't have an id in that scope (some debugging will clear any doubt).

Comment: @AlessandroLucarini this.children is not a subDoc, but an array of subDocs. this.children[0].id will be the id you looking for.

Comment: I was trying to use this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#finding-a-subdocument